# Delete from collection B based on results from collection A

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 big collections, which are cross-used (small data is in collection A, while big binary data is in collection B). They all have the same `key`, now I want to delete everything from both collections based on something like:

```
db.A.remove({ field1: 10 })
```

field1 only exists in collection A, but I need to delete the results with same `key` from collection B. So far I made a cursor with `db.A.find()` and delete everything in `db.B` one by one. It works, but is terribly slow on bigger collections like 50k+ items, hence it does like 100k operations to just delete items based on query. Is there a better way? 
$in also has a limit for number of IDs, so I'm searching for some nice solution...

With the $in operator and Mongoose, i could came with something like:

```
var _ids = [];
A.find({ field1: 10 }).stream().on('data', function(data) {
  _ids.push(data._id);
}).once('close', function() {
  A.remove({ field1: 10 });
  B.remove({ _id: { $in: _ids } });
});
```

It kinda works, but I'm afraid there will be a query limit hit with $in operator.

Comment: Do you have any example of your code? (Especially with $in operator)

Comment: @MoiSyme i've added what i could come up with Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Mongoose, but I can give you a possible solution in mongodb shell and I believe that you can make the appropriate code in Mongoose. You can make something like that:

```
var _ids = db.A.distinct('_id',{field1: 10}); 
B.remove({_id:{$in:_ids}});
A.remove({field1:10});
```

Comment: Yes it's almost the same, the problem still persists thought - if the amount of _ids exceeds default 16MB limit, it will fail

Comment: Ok the only possible solution (that I can think) then is the pagination process. For example you have to make an iteration i=0 to n/500 and find({field1:10}).skip(i*500).limit(500), then extract the ids for 500 entries and remove them at the from B collection.

Comment: Ahhh you are right, pagination with grouping! This might solve the limits